# Libgdx rotate ModelInstance towards PerspectiveCamera

Tags: java, android, rotation, libgdx, perspectivecamera

When I translate my ModelInstance up, I see the bottom of my ModelInstance and I want to see it correctly (rotate the ModelInstance towards the PerspectiveCamera).

Here is an example :

In the create method:

```
AssetManager assetManager = new AssetManager();
assetManager.load("ship.obj", Model.class);
assetManager.finishLoading();
Model model = assetManager.get("ship.obj", Model.class);
ModelInstance modelInstanceShip= new ModelInstance(model);
```

In the render method:

```
modelInstanceShip.transform.setTranslation(
perspectiveCamera.position.x,
perspectiveCamera.position.y + 200, 
perspectiveCamera.position.z -10);

modelBatch.begin(perspectiveCamera);
modelBatch.render(modelInstanceShip, environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

How can I rotate ModelInstance towards PerspectiveCamera in Libgdx?

Something like?

```
modelInstanceShip.transform.rotate() //Towards perspectiveCamera?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show some Code or we need a huge marble to help you. Best would be a minimal working example. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes you need to calculate the direction vector from the ship to the camera. If you got this you need to rotate the current direction vector of the ship to this calculated vector.

Comment: For that reason, you will need to write a ship class which has the current direction vector and the translation and rotation stuff (translate/rot. inside of the update method)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you show me some code in the answer to get a better understanding ?